Shift roster (calendar) - mathematic optimization algorithm
I have question about heuristic searching problem - I need to plan shift roster for workers.
My solution is to use some bio-inspired algorithm. My implementation is:
I created list of timeframes (shift time from-to) and then algorithm is assigning workers to those timeframes, which is creating individuals (evolutionary approach) – protentional solutions in population like this:
Time: Time are hours from begin of the month
Timeframes (TF) = TF1 {07:30-19:30}, TF2 {19:30-31:30}, TF3 {31:30-43:30}, …., TFx {Timen-Timen+1}
Workers (W) = W1, W2, W3, ….., Wy
Individual(I) = TF1->W2, TF2->W1, TF3->W2, TF4->W8, … , TFx –> W1…y
Population (P)= I1, I2, I3, …., Iz
Populations size = 100
Problem is, that there is quite a lot of timeframes (120), which mean high dimensionality to solve. Other way around like add timeframes to persons seems more complicated, plus I don’t see any benefits. My original approach was to use jDE and then I tried GA. None of them worked. Both GA and DE are working with list of W as hyperspace and the try different neighbor points, but in reality are all variables in W independent, so maybe that’s the problem and that’s why I didn’t implemented something like PSO (in my opinion, that’s basically same as DE).
jDE (rand/1, exponential crossing) - gives quick convergence until some point, but then it stopped in local minimum 20-40 differences against ideal plan (in 120 timeframes), which is far from ideal. Plus, in more timeframes (250+) it is absolutely lost and give no solution.
GA (rank selection, dynamic n-point cross selection) – even worse, extremely slow convergence with 350+ differences (in 120 timeframes) against ideal plan.
Is there any better algorithm for this problem or my approach is bad and I am missing something important? Maybe some metaheuristic search like Simulated annealing/TABU search as hybrid solution to search local minimum after jDE?
Edit1: More detailed description of a problem.
Example:

there is 12 workers (cops which need to have planned a patrol)
there is one patrol contain 2 members, members change in every 12 hours (can vary from 1h to 23h)
so in this case in every shift are 2 workers (can be from 1 to 3)
each worker can work for ~160 hours/month
there are law constraints about break between shifts etc
there are preferred orders of shift (2x day shift, 2x night shift, 4 days of break and again)
some workers can be sick/have vacation
others things to count

So cost function is quite complex with multi-modal evaluation.
Here is first and last iteration of algorithm. Note: differences is one of multi-objective minimum searching problem. For sake of simplicity, is this simplest cost function
iteration 1 - fitness 300,000,000,791 | differences - 791 | time - 14:22:58
iteration 6771 - fitness 53 | differences 53 | time 14:25:42
As you can see in this simple set up (120 shifts and only one multi-objective problem) is pretty quick convergence, but here is it stuck forever.

Pic 1 - List of workers and patrols with shifts to plan

Pic 2 - iteration 6771 proposal. As you can see, not all workers have 7, 7, 19, 19 start shift time. Cost function prioritize missing shift in start and end of shift combo like 7, 19, 19, or 7, 7, 19 and not 7, break, 19, 19

Could you give a more detailed description of the problem? What are the decisions to take, the objective, the constraints?

@fontanf I have updated post

Is there a reason why you are trying to use metaheuristics as opposed to a MILP or MIQP model?
